# newbie: how to get dynamic links for current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Im trying to figure out how to get a dynamic link for example

- /users/user1/show
- /users/user1/edit
  or
- /profiles/1/

How would I create a route that I could insert in my views like a view_profile_path and that would include the id or username of a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you need something like this in **config/routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

You can later check your REST-ful resource routes by issuing the command:

```
rake routes
```

This way you have a more natural approach to your routes in which your users will be bound to one or more profiles, therefore you may use something like:

```
user_profile_path(@user)
```

to create an appropriate link to a user's profile.

Answer (score 3):

in `config/routes.rb` you need to add 1 simple line:

```
resources :users
```

and get all this stuff

```
HTTP Verb   Path            action    named helper

GET         /users          index     users_path
GET         /users/new      new       new_user_path
POST        /users          create    users_path
GET         /users/:id      show      user_path(:id)
GET         /users/:id/edit edit      edit_user_path(:id)
PUT         /users/:id      update    user_path(:id)
DELETE      /users/:id      destroy   user_path(:id)
```

You can read about rails routes in [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)